# Realizar una petición DELETE

Tags: php, curl

Tengo un problema tratando de enviar un parametro usando:

```
curl -X DELETE <url> -d id=1
```

Al momento de ejecutar el comando me marca el siguiente error:

```
Undefined index: id
```

Se que este error me esta diciendo que no le esta pasando algún valor a la variable id, pero no estoy seguro del porque.

**Función Curl**:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/curl/config.php';
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; 
$id = ["id" => $_POST['id']];

function deleteData($url,$method,$id){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($id));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

   if(!$response){
       return false;
   } else {
      print_r($response);
   }
   curl_close($ch);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener los parámetros enviados por el método `DELETE`, debes leer el stream [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Puedes obtener un string con los parámetros serializados con [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) y convertirlos a un array con [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php):

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $request_params);
```

Tu código quedaría al final de esta manera:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/curl/config.php';
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $request_params);
$id = ["id" => $request_params['id']];

function deleteData($url,$method,$id){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($id));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

   if(!$response){
       return false;
   } else {
      print_r($response);
   }
   curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: Para completar la respuesta, lo que no está definido es índice id dentro del array $_POST, justamente porque lo que se envió es un DELETE en lugar de un POST.